# How to add a command for syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2

Sublime Text 2 does not highlight `require_relative`, but does highlight `require`.

How to add `require_relative` to the list of words for syntax highlighting for Ruby?

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby.tmLanguage, Change this line:

```
<string>\b(require|gem)\b</string>
```

to

```
<string>\b(require|gem|require_relative)\b</string>
```

The Ruby.tmLanguage file can be found from within Sublime Text 2 with `Sublime Text > Preferences > Browse Packages`.

Comment: You can write it more succinctly as `/\b(require(?:_relative)?|gem)\b/`

Comment: Tin Man, you need to remove the slashes, they are implied in the settings file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit the Ruby tmLanguage file.  This should be located in your "sublime install directory"/Data/Packages/Ruby.   The format maybe a little strange but sublime text docs gives you instructions on how to edit the tmLanguages files here http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html